# Scary looking update - ca-certificates_20190110~16.04.1_all.deb

Tags: updates

I just updated by 16.04 desktop install and it updated the package ca-certificates_20190110~16.04.1_all.deb. The output below looked pretty scary to me with certificates being removed and added to what appear to me to be random countries. I have no idea what certificates are for or whether this is to be expected?

```
> Preparing to unpack .../ca-certificates_20190110~16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking ca-certificates (20190110~16.04.1) over (20170717~16.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up ca-certificates (20190110~16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20190110~16.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
10 added, 31 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

>Adding debian:GDCA_TrustAUTH_R5_ROOT.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R6.pem
Adding debian:OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GC_CA.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_EV_Root_Certification_Authority_ECC.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_EV_Root_Certification_Authority_RSA_R2.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_Root_Certification_Authority_ECC.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_Root_Certification_Authority_RSA.pem
Adding debian:TrustCor_ECA-1.pem
Adding debian:TrustCor_RootCert_CA-1.pem
Adding debian:TrustCor_RootCert_CA-2.pem
Removing debian:ACEDICOM_Root.pem
Removing debian:AddTrust_External_Root.pem
Removing debian:AddTrust_Low-Value_Services_Root.pem
Removing debian:AddTrust_Public_Services_Root.pem
Removing debian:AddTrust_Qualified_Certificates_Root.pem
Removing debian:CA_Disig_Root_R1.pem
Removing debian:CNNIC_ROOT.pem
Removing debian:Camerfirma_Chambers_of_Commerce_Root.pem
Removing debian:Camerfirma_Global_Chambersign_Root.pem
Removing debian:Certinomis_-_Autorité_Racine.pem
Removing debian:Certum_Root_CA.pem
Removing debian:China_Internet_Network_Information_Center_EV_Certificates_Root.pem
Removing debian:Comodo_Secure_Services_root.pem
Removing debian:Comodo_Trusted_Services_root.pem
Removing debian:DST_ACES_CA_X6.pem
Removing debian:GeoTrust_Global_CA_2.pem
Removing debian:PSCProcert.pem
Removing debian:Security_Communication_EV_RootCA1.pem
Removing debian:Swisscom_Root_CA_1.pem
Removing debian:Swisscom_Root_CA_2.pem
Removing debian:Swisscom_Root_EV_CA_2.pem
Removing debian:TURKTRUST_Certificate_Services_Provider_Root_2007.pem
Removing debian:TÜBİTAK_UEKAE_Kök_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sağlayıcısı_-_Sürüm_3.pem
Removing debian:TÜRKTRUST_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sağlayıcısı_H5.pem
Removing debian:UTN_USERFirst_Hardware_Root_CA.pem
Removing debian:Visa_eCommerce_Root.pem
Removing debian:Certplus_Root_CA_G1.pem
Removing debian:Certplus_Root_CA_G2.pem
Removing debian:OpenTrust_Root_CA_G1.pem
Removing debian:OpenTrust_Root_CA_G2.pem
Removing debian:OpenTrust_Root_CA_G3.pem
done.
Updating Mono key store
Linux Cert Store Sync - version 4.2.1.0
Synchronize local certs with certs from local Linux trust store.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

>I already trust 148, your new list has 127
Certificate added: C=CN, O="GUANG DONG CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY CO.,LTD.", CN=GDCA TrustAUTH R5 ROOT
Certificate added: OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R6, O=GlobalSign, CN=GlobalSign
Certificate added: C=CH, O=WISeKey, OU=OISTE Foundation Endorsed, CN=OISTE WISeKey Global Root GC CA
Certificate added: C=US, S=Texas, L=Houston, O=SSL Corporation, CN=SSL.com EV Root Certification Authority ECC
Certificate added: C=US, S=Texas, L=Houston, O=SSL Corporation, CN=SSL.com EV Root Certification Authority RSA R2
Certificate added: C=US, S=Texas, L=Houston, O=SSL Corporation, CN=SSL.com Root Certification Authority ECC
Certificate added: C=US, S=Texas, L=Houston, O=SSL Corporation, CN=SSL.com Root Certification Authority RSA
Certificate added: C=PA, S=Panama, L=Panama City, O=TrustCor Systems S. de R.L., OU=TrustCor Certificate Authority, CN=TrustCor ECA-1
Certificate added: C=PA, S=Panama, L=Panama City, O=TrustCor Systems S. de R.L., OU=TrustCor Certificate Authority, CN=TrustCor RootCert CA-1
Certificate added: C=PA, S=Panama, L=Panama City, O=TrustCor Systems S. de R.L., OU=TrustCor Certificate Authority, CN=TrustCor RootCert CA-2
10 new root certificates were added to your trust store.
Import process completed.
Done
done.
```